# Each component of metrizable locally euclidean space is a manifold

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, manifolds, connectedness

The following is an exercise in Munkres Topology Chapter 8 supplementary exercises(p 316, exercise 9).

> Let $X$ be a space that is locally $m$-euclidean. Show that if $X$ is metrizable, then each component of $X$ is an $m$-manifold.

The following are definitions.

> A space $X$ is said to be locally $m$-euclidean if for each $x \in X$, there is a neighborhood of $x$ that is homeomorphic to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

> An $m$-manifold is a Hausdorff space with a countable basis which is locally $m$-euclidean.

Comment: The key is to use paracompactness.  See https://mathoverflow.net/a/237/75 for instance.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.